# Connections from Xib file to viewController never initialize

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm facing this strange problem (and even though a lot of answers talk about it) for some reason, I haven't been able to solve it.

I have a tabbar controller > navigation controller > tableView - where I load a list of music tracks. When someone touches a button (in an extended cell area) I intend to load a Music Player. Earlier, I was trying to load a music player as a separate view but then found it hard to manage the view states (even though it played perfectly well), so I decided to load the music player as an attached subview. I have been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbuL-vUDBhg) where a draggable view is demoed like a notification centre.

The view works perfectly, I can drag and see the whole player, etc. However I have two issues: 
1. How do I dismiss this view / end the music player? (minor issue)
2. All outlet connections and actions are NEVER initialized. (major issue)

Since I would like the music player to have a title, pause/play, timeline slider, etc. I've created outlet connections / actions (that have worked previously) but since I followed the tutorial and created a separate xib, the connections never initialize.

Steps taken so far:

- Checked for custom class - the file owner is correct still doesn't work
- Checked all outlet connections - they're all correct
- Recreated all the files with different connection names (no copy pasting) - still doesn't work
- Created the cocoa touch class first and let Xcode create the xib for me - still doesn't work

Error I get is:

**for outlets**
*this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX*

**for actions** (e.g. after pressing a button)
*unrecognized selector sent to instance ZZZ*

where,
xxx - is often the label first and then the button and then the activity indicator. 
zzz - is the hexadecimal value for the UI component Xcode assigns.

About the ViewController: it is inheriting from FXBlurView (as in tutorial). I tried to get it to inherit from UIViewController and still no luck. Right now the file is blank and yet the outlets don't work, so I think the issue isn't with the file but is with the connections from the Xib to the swift file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I found the mistake, I was connecting everything to the file owner, however after following [this](https://www-stackoverflow-info.blogspot.ca/2016/02/loaded-nib-but-view-outlet-was-not-set.html), I realized that I should first select my parent view, then connect all outlets (of the customer class) to the components in the view via IB.

However, two issues still remain: 
1. A label and a button remain uninstantiated on loading. For some strange reason they're nil (while other labels work just fine). Then, when I press the button, it works fine as well and start behaving as expected. I tried to change this uninstantiated label text through an action and that works as well, the only time it doesn't work is when the class instantiates (I change the label text on load). Not sure why :(

2. Dismissing the sub-view.

Comment: That error means you have an outlet set somewhere that is no longer connected to the class.  Try resetting all of them and confirming each View does not have any outlets connected that shouldn't be in the inspector tab

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. Even created new views with different connection names to a blank VC file - doesn't work.

Comment: In some cases, the people using copy paste to create new .xib files, and the  outlets are duplicated. You can check this.

Comment: Yes, to ensure this wasn't the case, I create a new xib and recreated all UX components - the view loaded fine. Then I started adding connections - the actions load fine until you execute them - it results in error: "*unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxxxx* (hexadecimal)." And label and other **outlets** never work at all - even in the first instance - don't let the view load.